# Java: Searching For Specific Bytes in a binary file and replacing or omitting said bytes

Tags: java, binary, byte, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I need to search for the word "test" in a file. The file i am using is a text file but i will be using this on binary files.

The following code looks like it should work to me but it doesn't work. I am able to display the instances of "test" within the file but I can't get it to basically Not write "test" in the created file.

Any help please?

```
public static void makelabels(){
   File file = new File("test.txt");
   // Check if File Exists.
   if(file.exists()){
     //Do work boy!!!!
   int length = (int) file.length();
   System.out.println("\nFile Length is "+length+" bytes");
   try{
   byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
   int i = 0;
   int count = 0;
   char c;
   FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
   FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("test2.txt");
   input.read(bytes);
   for(byte b:bytes){
     c = (char) b;
     if(Character.toString(c).equals("t")){
       if(Character.toString((char) bytes[i+1]).equals("e")){
         if(Character.toString((char) bytes[i+2]).equals("s")){
           if(Character.toString((char) bytes[i+3]).equals("t")){
             count++;
             System.out.println("Found TEST " + count +" times");

           }
           else{
             output.write(b);
           }
         }
         else{
           output.write(b);
         }
       }
       else{
         output.write(b);
       }
     }
    else{
      output.write(b);
    }

     i++;
   }
   System.out.println("\n\n");
   System.out.println("Test Results\n\n");
   input.close();
   output.close();

   return;}

   catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
     System.out.println("\nFile Not Found");
   }
   catch(IOException ex){
     System.out.println("\nCan't Read File");
   }
 }
 else{
   System.out.println("\nFile Not Found!");
   return;
 }
 }
```

Thanks for amount of help you guys can offer.

I'm not getting an array problem.

Here is the test file content.

```
"this is a test
Please test me"
```

Here are my results

```
"this is a est
Please est me"
```

The code makes sense to me and really seems like it should work but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: The error you are getting is sometimes more important than a wall of code.

Comment: This code will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.` Strange that you didn't mention that. Inexplicable really.

Comment: I've updated the question. But to EJP no array problems sir. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend approaching it a different way instead of converting each individual to a byte.

```
byte[] match = "test".getBytes();
for(int i =0; i < 1 + bytes.length - match.length; i++){
  boolean flag = true;
  for(int j= 0; j < match.length; j++){
    if(match[j] != bytes[i+j]){
      flag = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(flag){
    count++;
    i+=match.length-1; // don't check these bytes anymore which will also cause them to not be written because it won't do the check below. 
  }else{
     output.write(b);
  }
}
```

The outer loop will go through each byte that could potentially begin the String you'd like to match. The inner loop will start at the beginning point and compare the following bytes. If all the bytes match, Flag will remain true. However, if there was a discrepancy, flag will be set to false. Thus if flag is true, increment the count.

Edit: the above code now increments the index the length of the string you're trying to match if it finds a match. It does this in opposition to writing to the output. From what I understand this is what you were trying to ask, but I'm unsure. If that wasn't what you wanted, can you explain a little more?

Comment: I will try this later today and let you know what I get. Thank you sir :)

Comment: I'm about to try this right now. After reading this it makes perfect sense. You will have made my day sir if it does. Thanks so much. I'll let you know if it helps :0

Comment: Ok so different method of attack but the same result :( how can i tell the program to not even output the bytes t e s t.? i think this is the problem. 

Btw thank you so much for the much cleaner code than I had. lol

Comment: Thanks again Matt, I actually found that worked until I noticed it didn't output the last couple of letters in the text file.  so instead of "Please (blank) me" it just says "Please (blank)" I'm sure i'm doing something wrong thanks man. You've been a big help

Comment: Ok dude, I just made the for loop use the length of the file rather than 1 + bytes.length-match.length. Not sure why that was added to begin with but i figure all i need is the size of the file itself. And it works.

Comment: Thanks again man. Sorry I can't up your rep as my rep has just been taken down just for asking the question lol

Comment: No worries, glad you got what you needed!